# PredictionIO Deploy issue

Tags: predictionio

I run `pio deploy`, and it appears there are no errors, however I am not sure that things are running without issue. Do any of the warnings below flag anything that would indicate that it is not working?

```
[INFO] [Runner$] Submission command: /opt/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-submit --class io.prediction.workflow.CreateServer --jars file:/opt/PredictionIO/loan/target/scala-2.10/template-scala-parallel-recommendation_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar,file:/opt/PredictionIO/loan/target/scala-2.10/template-scala-parallel-recommendation-assembly-0.1-SNAPSHOT-deps.jar --files file:/opt/PredictionIO/conf/log4j.properties,file:/opt/hbase-1.0.1.1/conf/hbase-site.xml --driver-class-path /opt/PredictionIO/conf:/opt/hbase-1.0.1.1/conf file:/opt/PredictionIO/lib/pio-assembly-0.9.4.jar --engineInstanceId AVFJgnyJSBmSB2aYjF3H --engine-variant file:/opt/PredictionIO/loan/engine.json --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 8000 --event-server-ip 0.0.0.0 --event-server-port 7070 --json-extractor Both --env PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_HBASE_TYPE=hbase,PIO_ENV_LOADED=1,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_NAME=pio_meta,PIO_FS_BASEDIR=/home/ubuntu/.pio_store,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=,PIO_HOME=/opt/PredictionIO,PIO_FS_ENGINESDIR=/home/ubuntu/.pio_store/engines,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_HDFS_TYPE=hdfs,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_HDFS_PATH=/home/ubuntu/.pio_store/models,PIO_STORAGE_SOURCES_ELASTICSEARCH_TYPE=elasticsearch,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_METADATA_SOURCE=ELASTICSEARCH,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_SOURCE=HDFS,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_NAME=pio_event,PIO_FS_TMPDIR=/home/ubuntu/.pio_store/tmp,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_MODELDATA_NAME=pio_model,PIO_STORAGE_REPOSITORIES_EVENTDATA_SOURCE=HBASE,PIO_CONF_DIR=/opt/PredictionIO/conf
[WARN] [WorkflowUtils$] Non-empty parameters supplied to com.polarisft.com.Preparator, but its constructor does not accept any arguments. Stubbing with empty parameters.
[WARN] [WorkflowUtils$] Non-empty parameters supplied to com.polarisft.com.Serving, but its constructor does not accept any arguments. Stubbing with empty parameters.
[ERROR] [HDFSModels] File pio_modelAVFJgnyJSBmSB2aYjF3H does not exist
[ERROR] [OneForOneStrategy] None.get
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PredictionIO is not able to fetch your trained model.
Try to check in pio-env.sh where the model is stored and it is reachable to predictionIO